# Jmeter passing two parameters to a custom function

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter I am able to get a custom function with one parameter passing work, however I am not able to get a custom function with two parameter passing working

In BeanShellFunction.bshrc I have defined

```
printStr1(String str1)
{
    System.out.println(str1);
}
printStr2(String str1, String str2)
{
    System.out.println(str1, str2);
}
```

In my Jmeter BeanShell Assertion I have

```
${__BeanShell(printStr1("hello"))}
${__BeanShell(printStr2("hello", "howAreYou"))}
```

---

I do see --> hello
I do not see the second function results 
somehow the 2nd parameter passing is not working

From jmeter log I see:
2018-04-11 18:17:56,348 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``printStr2("hello";'' Encountered "( \"hello\" ;" at line 1, column 10.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to amend your `printStr2` function as [PrintStream.println()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) 
   method can accept only a **single string**. Change it to something like:

   ```
   printStr2(String str1, String str2)
   {
       System.out.println(str1 + str2);
   }
   ```
2. As per JMeter [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   > If a function parameter contains a comma, then be sure to escape this with "\", otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter

   You need to amend your __Beanshell function call to escape the comma like:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(printStr2("hello "\, "howAreYou"),)}
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on using JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have [println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) with more than 1 parameter so `System.out.println(str1, str2)` will not compile.

If you want to concatenate strings just concatenate the strings in your `printStr2` method:

```
System.out.println(str1 + str2);
```

Consider moving to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) because Beanshell may be deprecated in JMeter.

Also notice there's a special `OUT` available:

> OUT - System.out - e.g. OUT.println("message")