# Jmeter Passing two variables to a custom function

Tags: jmeter

I asked this Q here --> [Jmeter passing two parameters to a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770046/jmeter-passing-two-parameters-to-a-custom-function)  but the answer I received is not helping me

I am not able to get a custom function with two variables passing working

In BeanShellFunction.bshrc I have defined

```
printStr2(String str1, String str2)
{
    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.println(str2);
}
```

In BeanShell assertion I have:

```
String Username = "ABC";
String Password ="XXX";
${__BeanShell(printStr2(Username , Password))}
```

but it is not working, I even tried

```
${__BeanShell(printStr2(Username \, Password))}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter passing two parameters to a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770046/jmeter-passing-two-parameters-to-a-custom-function)

Comment: _"the answer I received is not helping me"_ So tell the people who answered that, instead of just posting a duplicate with no information on why those answers didn't help...?!?  _"but it is not working"_ That is not a problem description. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working (note I needed a Base64 from Username and Password)

I tpassed the variable to function like this --> vars.get("temp")

```
temp = Username + ":" + Password;
vars.put("temp", new temp);
```

on a 2nd Bean Assertion

```
${__BeanShell(printStr3(vars.get("temp")))}
```

inside the function I did a vars.get("temp")  to get it

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting. The same applies to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

1. Create a file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation like `customFunction.groovy`
2. Amend your code to start with function return type:

   ```
   void printStr2(String str1, String str2)
   {
       System.out.println(str1);
       System.out.println(str2);
   }
   ```
3. Start JMeter as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -Jgroovy.utilities=customFunction.groovy
   ```
4. Call the code from `__groovy()` function like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(printStr2('ABC'\, 'XXX'),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Utility Function]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)